# Checking if variable is zero for both scalar and array

Tags: python

Say that I have a variable `x` that can either be a scalar or a 1d object like a list, numpy ndarray or a pandas series etc. I want to check whether it is a scalar and numerically equal to 0 (a list-like object only containing zeros should yield false, since not a scalar). What is the most concise and pythonic way of doing this?

A simple:

```
if x == 0:
    print("scalar == 0 detected")
```

does not work since numpy arrays compare elementwise (and throws the `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: Use `isinstance` and do the appropriate check for each possible type of `x`

Comment: How does `x` get set to a value of one of two very different types in the first place?

Comment: @chepner The case appeared in a loop over a list with lots of different types in it.

Comment: @DeepSpace I was wondering if there was a standard "covers-all-cases" solution but went with a np.isscalar check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found was

```
import numpy as np

if np.isscalar(x) and x == 0:
```

I post it here in case it helps anyone but am still interested if there are even more concise ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

if `x` is a `list' you can use

```
a = [0, 0, 0]
all(x==0 for x in a)
True
```

if it is `np.array` or `pd.DataFrame`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0 ,0 ,0])
(a==0).all()
True
```

If you want single solution you can convert your input to np.array and use the numpy version `(np.array(a)==0).all()`.

This is elegant but you need to "pay" the conversion to `numpy`.
If you really care about performance and most of your use cases are scalars and short lists, you may want to think twice if you want to "pay" this casting overhead.

```
a=0
(np.array(a)==0).all()
True

a=[0, 0, 0]
(np.array(a)==0).all()
True

a = np.array([0, 0, 0])
(np.array(a)==0).all()
True

a = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0])
(np.array(a)==0).all()
True
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and hope it will help others! My question was about the case where 1d objects — even if only containing 0 — evaluate to false.